# How to catch sqlite3.IntegrityError with pytest.raises?

Tags: python, sqlite, pytest

I am trying to catch a `sqlite3.IntegrityError` error with `pytest.raises()`.
Here's some toy code to illustrate the behavior.

```py
import sqlite3

import pytest


def func(cursor):
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Test (Name) VALUES ('Entry1')")
    except sqlite3.IntegrityError as e:
        print(e)


def test_func():
    connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    c = connection.cursor()

    c.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        Name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)
        """
    )

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Test (Name) VALUES ('Entry1')")

    with pytest.raises(sqlite3.IntegrityError) as e:
        func(cursor=c)

    assert str(e.value) == "UNIQUE constraint failed: Test.Name"
```

The code of my `func` actually throws the anticipated error and prints to stdout, because `Entry1` is already in the table and violates the `UNIQUE` restriction. However, the test fails. I don't understand why `pytest` didn't raise a `sqlite3.IntegrityError`. Here's the test's output:

```py
FAILED                                                 [100%]UNIQUE constraint failed: Test.Name

err.py:12 (test_func)
def test_func():
        connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
        c = connection.cursor()
    
        c.execute(
            """
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Test (
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            Name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)
            """
        )
    
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Test (Name) VALUES ('Entry1')")
    
        with pytest.raises(sqlite3.IntegrityError) as e:
>           func(cursor=c)
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'sqlite3.IntegrityError'>

err.py:28: Failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have already defined a `try-catch` block inside your function `func`, when the `sqlite3.IntegrityError` exception occurs, it is handled by the `except` inside your function rather than letting it be raised by `pytest.raises`. So just remove the try-except from your method and only keep the `cursor.execute` statement (or create a new one without it and use it in your test methods) or instead of handling the exception inside your `func`'s `except` block, you can `raise` it again.

Simple reproducible example:

```
def f():
    try:
        print(1/0)
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print(e)

def g():
    print(1/0)

def a():
    with pytest.raises(ZeroDivisionError) as e:
        f()
        # g()
```

This will raise the exception inside your `f()` and then throw `Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ZeroDivisionError'>`. If you call `g()` instead, it will execute normally.

Comment: This makes perfectly sense. Now I got it ;-)